# Stopping Duplication names on listview using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently i have a list view which is displaying information about the users 'medication' and the times due to take it. Currently depending how many times the user takes it during the day this is how many entries will be shown on the listview, pic is shown below:

.[image]

Currently im trying to duplicate this view on another page but im removing the dosage, time and weather it is taken or not, it will only contain the name but i wondering ifs it possible to be able to only have the medname show once on the list view and stop any duplication names? I will only be calling on the medname on the new listview.

This is how i am populating the listview:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets User Medication list
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The user meds.</returns>
    async public Task GetUserMeds()
    {


        MedicationList.ItemsSource = null;
        UserMedTimes.Clear(); //Clears the list before calling API (prevents duplication)

        main.Children.Add(MedicationList);
        main.Children.Remove(NoMeds);

        if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {

            main.Children.Remove(MedicationList);
            main.Children.Add(NoMeds);
            NoMeds.Text = "No Internet Connection - Please check your connection";
            NoMeds.Margin = new Thickness(35, 35, 20, 20);

            BusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        }

        else

        {
            BusyIndicator.IsRunning = true;

            //var usermed = await medicinemanager.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync<IEnumerable<usermedication>>("getusermednamejoin?userid=" + Helpers.Settings.UserKey + "", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, null);

            try
            {


                var usermeddosagetime = await medicinemanager.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync("getusermeddosagetime?userid=" + Helpers.Settings.UserKey, null, HttpMethod.Get, await App.LoadAPIKeyAsync(), null);


                var responseContent = await usermeddosagetime.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<UserMedDosagePayLoad>>(responseContent);

                //var usermeddosagetime = await medicinemanager.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync<IEnumerable<UserMedDosagePayLoad>>("getusermeddosagetime?userid=" + Helpers.Settings.UserKey + "", HttpMethod.Get, API, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
                //null, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, API, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

                Debug.WriteLine("UserMedDosageTime" + usermeddosagetime);

                foreach (UserMedDosagePayLoad item in user)
                {
                    UserMedTimes.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }



            FindNextDue(UserMedTimes);
```

Comment: yes, eliminate the duplicate entries from your data source

Comment: You can check for the condition 'contains'. Do not add the item in list if already present.

//
  foreach (UserMedDosagePayLoad   item in user)
            {
                if (UserMedTimes.Contains(item))
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    UserMedTimes.Add(items);
                }
            }